# How reasonable is deriving the key a corpus of RSA-PSS signed messages?

Tags: rsa, rsa-pss

Given access to a 2048 bit public key, a large corpus of 2048 bit plain text messages and their signatures (RSA-PSS with SHA256 as the hash and MGF)  are any of the following statements correct:

1. Increasing the number of of messages available significantly increases the likelihood an attacker can reverse the private key
2. Decreasing the plain text message size significantly increases the likelihood an attacker can reverse the private key

Note: by significantly I mean "before the heat death of the universe" becomes a few hundred years. If instead it becomes half the heat death of the universe, I'm less interested.

Comment: related https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51186/18298

Comment: Note that the hash over the message is integral part of PSS, so increasing or decreasing the message size does nothing (special) to the input of the PSS padding algorithm (MGF1) and of course neither to the subsequent OS2IP algorithm or final RSA exponentiation. So part 2 is only of interest if you skip the data hashing part all together. You could probably argue that the resulting scheme would not be PSS.

Comment: Personally, if you're talking about *reversing* PSS, I would expect you mean that you can retrieve the messages or hash during verification. That's something entirely different from retrieving the private key and breaking the cipher. Maybe it is a good idea to adjust the title accordingly. And welcome to crypto.SE, of course :)

Comment: I updated the title

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Verification requires knowledge of the message and/or its hash. The security definition of signatures usually addresses unforgability, maybe the question should point in that direction. But the answer is fairly simple: No, with data and computational power in realistic dimensions, this should not work unless you can break the computational assumptions of RSA or the hash function.

Comment: Not covered in the question, let's say the data being protected was either of two options: very small (<10 bytes), or medium (256bytes) in size but with insignificant amounts of variability in the messages (think JSON with placeholders for values). Does a large corpus (millions of messages and signatures weaken the signature scheme to the point that a reduction in crypto period is the right mitigation strategy?

Comment: I don't know what an "encryption period" is. If you want to reduce the amount of times that a private key can be used then you *count*, you don't specify a period. This is a common strategy when side channel attacks can be performed, but they should not be required just because you want to sign a large number of messages. As indicated before, the size of the messages is inconsequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't *know* any forgery algorithm which can do a better job if there are more signed messages available, or smaller signed messages available.

The best way we know to forge messages is to factor $n$.  The best algorithm we know to factor $n = pq$ when $2^{1023} < p < q < 2^{1024}$ are (near) uniform random primes, the general number field sieve, costs more than $e^{(\log n)^{1/3} (\log \log n)^{2/3}}$, and uses only the modulus $n$, without reference to any signed messages.

The standard PSS security theorem is that *if* you had an algorithm to forge signatures, then someone could use your signature forger as a subroutine in a program to invert $x \mapsto x^e \bmod n$ with essentially the same probability of success as the forger, and as many additional modular exponentiations as the forger makes hash or signing queries.  Consequently, PSS forgery can't be much *cheaper* than computing $e^{\mathit{th}}$ roots, but we don't know any way to actually do it besides factoring $n$ in order to compute $e^{\mathit{th}}$ roots in the first place.

Comment: I've added a note underneath the question about small messages, something still missing from your answer. Feel free to integrate it if you agree with it.

Comment: By "algorithm that can do a better job" do you mean algorithm that factor RSA-PSS better or algorithms that to protect messages better?

Comment: Yup, it is - thanks!

Comment: It answers both questions, so in my opinion it is indeed better.